# sampling all combinations based on an ID constrain in a loop in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with an ID and sub ID column and other explanatory variables. I need to sample all different combinations based one the ID and subID columns. Each time only 1 row from each ID category can be selected.

```
mydata <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
                 SubId = c(1,2,3,1,2),
                 Var_1 = c(16, 18, 20, 10, 11))
```

What I would want as an outcome is to receive a dataframe with a unique combination for each iteration of the loop until all combinations are complete and all different dataframes can be retrieved. Only 1 row per ID can be selected each time.An example of the first 4 loop results is given below

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfKXd.png)

Comment: Please revise your question, your code doesn't work.

Comment: My bad,i have edited the post!